# How to get size in bytes of HttpWebRequest and WebResponse?

Tags: c#, http, web

I'm making a lot of GET requests to our server as part of a stress test.  I'd like to be able to get the size in bytes of all the `HttpWebRequests` and corresponding `WebResponses`.  Any ideas?

---

**EDIT**
I'd like the size of the total request/response, not just the payload.  The payload is an XML feed, which I'm currently getting the size of.

Comment: You need the size of the total request/response, including HTTP headers or just the payload?

Comment: Am i missing something? why don't you use for ex `httpWebRequests.GetResponse().ContentLength `

Comment: @L.B, because if the remote server doesn't set the `Content-Length` HTTP response header (for example http://google.com doesn't, also any server that's doing chunked response or streaming will never set this header) all you're gonna get with this property is the integer value of -1.

Comment: Exactly, I don't set the `Content-Length` for the request, and it's also not set for the response.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov At least you will read the response stream. Is it hard to get the length of it?

Comment: @nissemand it is available in *response* not in *request*.

Comment: @L.B I've set a break point where I get the `WebResponse`, and the `Content-Length` attribute is -1.

Comment: @nissemand, that's normal, the server simply didn't set the Content-Length response header. But even if it had, you would have gotten the total size of the response payload, it wouldn't have included the headers which apparently you also need to account for.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, I see.  I guess getting the size of the payload is the most important thing, as it should be most of the actual response.  But ideally I'd like the whole response size.  If I get the size of all the headers and add that to the payload size, will that give me the entire response size?

Comment: What if the response is gzipped and I want the number of bytes read from the network and not the size after decompression?

Comment: @NathanBaulch Hm, not a clue really.  The only thing I can think of is somehow measuring the size before decompression.

Answer (score 0):

For the `HttpWebRequest` I ended up just summing the size of the headers.

For the `WebResponse` I summed the size of the headers and the payload.  The payload was an XML feed, so I converted that to a `string` and then got the size in bytes.

With regards to the significance of taking the `WebResponse` headers into consideration, for an example response the headers were 572 bytes and the payload was 10,356 bytes.  So the headers were approximately 5% of the total response size.

Answer (score -1):

Use a tool called http://fiddler2.com/ it will give you all the necessary information. Export the data and add up the body size.

To do this pragmatically you have to check the content length of each request and add it to a variable. MSDN has code samples on how to access the content length.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.contentlength(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contentlength(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for responding!  Is there any way to do this programmatically?

Comment: `Content-Length` doesn't help me, because they're both set to -1.

Comment: @Felix you need to check `Content-Length` after sending the request.